# How to get records that have list of related records in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a table called `products` and another table called `specs`. Every product has many specs and every spec belongs to many products.

This way we have a many to many relationship. I've added a column in the pivot table named `ps_id` which is always unique.

Lets say I have a list of `ps_id` and I need those products that have exactly these related records.

I tried to use this query but it returns those products that at least have one of those `ps_id`s which is not what I need here.

```
// App\Models\Product
public function specs(): BelongsToMany {
    return $this->belongsToMany(ProductSpec::class, 'map_product_spec', 'product_id', 'spec_id');
}

public function product_spec_mapping(): HasMany {
    return $this->hasMany(MapProductSpec::class, 'service_id');
}
```

```
// ProductController
Product::whereHas('product_spec_mapping', function($q) {
    $q->whereIn('ps_id', $psIdArray);
});
```

How can I get those products that have all these related records?

Comment: Can you provide example of the records and what result do you expect from those? Also, what is `product_spec_mapping` actually? you barely explain anything about it.

Comment: @rifqyabdl - I found a solution for it, so now it works perfectly.

Comment: @Hooman then pls provide the answer and mark it the correct one to close this thread.

Answer (score -1):

For many to many relationships you need a pivot table. Also, both models should define a belongsToMany relationship, not a hasMany.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: This is an irrelevant answer, I do have those relations.